# Patching module raises module not found error

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I use jdk 11 and try to understand `--patch-module` option for java compiler. Here is the simple module I have:

```
mdl-platform
      |
      |
      |___com.test.mdl.platform
      |            |
      |            |___ ...
      |            |
      |            |___Patch.java
      |
      |___module-info.java
```

`module-info.java`:

```
module com.test.mdl.plarform {
    exports com.test.mdl.platform;
}
```

`Patch.java`:

```
public class Patch { }
```

I have `Patch.java` file and wanted to patch the module with it. I tried:

***I.***

```
$ javac --patch-module com.test.mdl.platform=mdl-plarform/src/main/java/ \
                mdl-plarform/src/main/java/com/test/mdl/platform/Patch.java 
error: module not found: com.test.mdl.platform
1 error
```

I ran also some fake module path and it worked fine (produced a valid `class` file):

***II.***

```
$ javac --patch-module com.test.mdl.platform=some/fake/path/ \
      mdl-plarform/src/main/java/com/test/mdl/platform/Patch.java
```

So why did the first example fail, but the directory existed and contained valid `module-info.java`, but the second worked ok even the path did not exist?

Comment: for one it might be trying to override the `com.test.mdl.platform` module with itself(or another `com.test.mdl.platform`) possibly when you specify the `module-info.java` directory in the input. on the other side, for the latter, there is no such possibility given an empty or invalid directory.

Comment: @Naman At least for the latter case the reasonable behavior might be to print an error as well I guess. Unfortunately all the documentation I could find was the JEP https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261 which did not cover such cases

Comment: did you compile your all java files?

Comment: @St.Antario What happens when you specify just `javac --patch-module com.test.mdl.platform=some/fake/path/` ? and the other alternative `javac --patch-module com.test.mdl.platform=mdl-plarform/src/main/java/com/test/mdl/platform/Path.java`?

Comment: @Naman You mean without any files to compile? It prints `no input files` as expected. I tried a few more examples and noticed that examples like `javac --patch-module fake.module=fake/path mdl-plarform/src/main/java/com/test/mdl/platform/Patch.java` also work fine so it means invalid `--patch-module` arguments seem to be simply ignored.

Comment: @ErHarshRathore I built the module as a `jar` file.

Comment: I'm not sure what actually you are trying to achieve. For `--patch-module` you need two things: (1) and existing module, and (2) additional sources outside the module, that should be compiled *as if* belonging to the module. In the given layout I only see one module *containing* a file that is called `Patch.java` but not patching anything since it already belongs to the module. What am I missing?

Comment: @StephanHerrmann The mostly confused thing I did not understand was why fake paths were ignored and no errors were printed (case *__II__*). The behavior turned to be as if no patches are made and the file being compiled is treated as if it belongs to the unnamed module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave some research regarding how `javac` works with the option `--patch-module`.

***I. Valid --patch-module path and module name which is not in module path***

```
$ javac --patch-module com.test.mdl.platform=mdl-plarform/src/main/java/ \
                mdl-plarform/src/main/java/com/test/mdl/platform/Patch.java 
error: module not found: com.test.mdl.platform
1 error
```

This fails.

`Javac` applies regular [module path scan](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/ModuleFinder.java#l174) to lookup the module specified in the left hand side of `--patch-module` equality (`com.test.mdl.platform` in this particular case).

For this module which is not in module path it obviously fails and the related `module not found` error is [reported](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Modules.java#l1387). The module `com.test.mdl.platform` is not in the module path so the behavior is expected.

***II. Valid module name and fake path***

```
$ javac --patch-module com.test.mdl.platform=some/fake/path/ \
      mdl-plarform/src/main/java/com/test/mdl/platform/Patch.java
```

This works "ok".

The reason is that `javac` checks the path specified in the right hand side of the `--patch-module` argument for correctness. **The path is correct iff it contains (either directly or indirectly) the file being compiled**.

The check is performed in the [com/sun/tools/javac/file/Locations.java](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/file/Locations.java#l1087). As can be seen it is simply loops over the `Path` `mdl-plarform/src/main/java/com/test/mdl/platform/Patch.java` getting parent on each iteration and comparing with the `some/fake/path/`.

If the path is incorrect then `null` is returned and [the module is not being patched](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Modules.java#l455). The file is treated as belonging to the unnamed module in this case

***III. Path exists, but contains neither `module-info.java` nor `module-info.class`***

```
$ javac --patch-module java.logging=mdl-plarform \ 
      mdl-plarform/src/main/java/com/test/mdl/platform/Patch.java
```

This works ok.

The reason is that the module `java.logging` is contained in the runtime image and can be found during module lookup. The next step is to [find either `module-info.java` or `module-info.class`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/ModuleFinder.java#l356) in the directory. In this case it fails since it does not contain it, then it falls back to lookup the `module-info.class` in the runtime image which succeeds.

***IV. Valid module name and module path, but module name mismatch***

```
$ javac --patch-module java.logging=mdl-plarform/src/main/java \
      mdl-plarform/src/main/java/com/test/mdl/platform/Patch.java

mdl-plarform/src/main/java/module-info.java:1: error: module name com.test.mdl.plarform does not match expected name java.logging
module com.test.mdl.plarform {
^
error: cannot access module-info
  cannot resolve modules
2 errors
```

This fails.

After the `module-info.java` was found in the directory specified in the `--patch-module` it is then parsed and the module name it contains [is checked for equality with the name specified in the `--patch-module`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Modules.java#l324). In this case we have a mismatch so the related error is printed.

I checked this behavior by simply debugging `javac` with the regular java debugger. So the only intention of that was to explain what was going on in the cases described in the question.